# Circular Linked List infinitely looping

Tags: java

I'm going over data structures with my java book and i'm needing to recreate a circular linked list. I'm having issues with this linked list infinitely looping and cannot figure out why. I'm able to insert the values into the list, however printing and deleting the values seems to infinitely loop the values initially inserted. How can I change my List class to avoid infinitely looping?

Output:

```
30, 5, 15, 20, 10, 30, 5, 15, 20, 10, 30, 5, 15, 20, 10, ...
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CircularList theList = new CircularList();
    theList.insert(10);
    theList.insert(20);
    theList.insert(15);
    theList.insert(5);
    theList.insert(30);

    theList.displayList();
    System.out.println(theList.delete());
    theList.delete(15);
    theList.displayList();       

    while (!theList.isEmpty()) {
        Link aLink = theList.delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted: " + aLink);           
    }
    if (!theList.isEmpty()) 
        System.out.println("Program error");
    else
        System.out.println("Program success");

}
```

CircularList.class

```
class CircularList {

private Link current;
private Link prev;

public CircularList() {
    // implement: set both current and prev to null
    current = prev = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    // implement
    return (current == null); // true if current is empty
}

public void insert(int id) {
    // implement: insert the new node behind the current node
    Link newLink = new Link(id);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        prev = current = newLink;
    } else {
        prev.next = newLink;
        newLink.next = current;
        current = newLink;
    }
}

public Link delete() {
    // implement: delete the node referred by current
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Link temp = current;
        current = current.next;
        return temp;
    } else 
        return null;
}

public Link delete(int id) {
    // implement: delete the node with value id
    // if no node with the id exists, return null
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // Link current; // start probe at beginning
    Link prev = current; // start previous at current 

    while (current != null && current.equals(current)) {
        prev = current; //save previous link
        current = current.next; // move to next Link
    }

    if (current == current.next)
        current = current.next;
    else if (current != null)
        prev.next = current.next;
    return current;

}

public void displayList() {
    // implement: print all the list element values once, each value seperated by comma
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.printf(current + ", ");
        current = current.next;
    }
}
}
```

Link.class

```
class Link {

private int id;
Link next;

public Link(int id) {
    // implement
    this.id = id;
    next = null;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a *circular* list, `current` will never be null in `delete(int id)` and `displayList()` unless the list is empty.

You'll have to remember where you started looking / printing and break if you get back to the starting `Link`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a circle goes on forever you should probably set a start/stop index:

```
public void displayList() {
    // implement: print all the list element values once, each value seperated by comma
     Link start = current;
     if (start == null)
        return;
     do {
        System.out.printf(current + ", ");
        current = current.next;
     } while (current != start)
}
```